# Case statment based on a count

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, count, case

I want to do a case statement based on the results of a count.

Something like:

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN count(distinct column) = 1
            THEN Foo
        WHEN count(distinct column) = 2
            THEN foo2
    END,
    column2
FROM
    TABLE
```

The above throws errors such as:

```
Column 'column2' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in an aggregate function and there is no GROUP BY clause.
```

I've tried a few other variations like this, but to no avail.

Using MS SQL 2005.

Comment: It might be better to explain the problem you are actually trying to solve...

Comment: Also tell us which RDBMS you are using.

Comment: @Mitch - basically, I need to select when column like '%term%' if there are multiple values for it (e.g. "dog, cat, goat, foo"), and I just need the single value otherwise.

Comment: It seems you are going a `COUNT()` without a `GROUP BY` which means you collect (counting) all rows into one. So, column2 can't really be shown. What can be shown is `MAX(column2)` or `COUNT(column2)` or `SUM(column2)` or other aggegate function on column2.

Comment: @ypercube - MS SQL 2005.

Comment: What can't you get from error message? It contains comprehensive description of what you have done wrong.

Comment: I guess you need something complex because your table has columns not normalized. Post a few rows of your table and what you would like the query to show.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL CASE STATEMENT in COUNT CLAUSE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/795341/sql-case-statement-in-count-clause)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this resolved yesterday. I was able to accomplish what I needed by joining in the table twice with different aliases, and using different join conditions for each. That allowed me to avoid needing to do the count because I had special-purpose tables that only had the correct values.

Sorry for the abstract code, but the result was similar to:

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN table1.field IS NOT NULL
            THEN table1alias1.column1
        WHEN table2.field IS NOT NULL
            THEN table1alias2.column1
    END,
    column2
FROM
    TABLE0
    LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE1 on TABLE0.id = TABLE1.field AND
        TABLE1.column1 LIKE '%foo%' as TABLE1ALIAS1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN TABL1 on TABLE0.id = TABLE1.field AND
        TABLE1.column1 LIKE '%fork%' as TABLE1ALIAS2
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to GROUP BY column2:

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN count(distinct column) = 1
            THEN Foo
        WHEN count(distinct column) = 2
            THEN foo2
    END,
    column2
FROM
    TABLE
GROUP BY Column2
```